# Why string getting from file is not equal to common string?

Tags: python, file-handling

I am on python 3.5 and want to find the matched words from a file. The word I am giving is `awesome` and the very first word in the `.txt` file is also `awesome`. Then why `addedWord` is not equal to `word`? Can some one give me the reason?

**myWords.txt**

```
awesome
shiny
awesome
clumsy
```

**Code for matching**

```
addedWord = "awesome"
        with open("myWords.txt" , 'r') as openfile:
                for word in openfile:
                    if addedWord is word:
                        print ("Match")
```

I also tried as :

```
 d = word.replace("\n", "").rstrip()
 a = addedWord.replace("\n", "").rstrip()
      if a is d:
          print ("Matched :" +word)
```

I also tried to get the class of variables by `typeOf(addedWord)` and `typeOf(word)` Both are from `'str'` class but are not equal. Is any wrong here?

Comment: You're comparing using `is` which compares object identity rather than value. If they are in different places in memory with the same value, their identity is different.

Comment: You should compare strings with `==`. Operator `is` checks if addedWord is the same object as word

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Those two strings will never be the same object, so you should not use `is` to compare them. Use `==`.

Your intuition to strip off the newlines was spot-on, but you just need a single call to `strip()` (it will strip all whitespace including tabs and newlines).

Comment: Your advice is correct, but your assertion is wrong. Two string may sometimes be the same object, but whether they are or are not is not assured.

Comment: Right -- fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

1) Strings returned from iterating files include the trailing newline. As you suspected, you'll need to `.strip()`, `.rstrip()` or `.replace()` the newline away.

2) String comparison should be performed with `==`, not `is`.

So, try this:

```
    if addedWord == word.strip():
       print ("Match")
```

Comment: Oops, just noticed my code snippet was wrong. Fixed.